# My teacher told me that my code was junk,Why?

Tags: c

Is there a big difference between these two algorithms?

This one is mine:

```
void MergeList(sqList la,sqList lb,sqList *lc){
  int j,k,n=0;

  for (j = la.length - 1, k = lb.length - 1; j >= 0 && k >= 0; ){
    if (*(la.elem + j) > *(lb.elem + k)){
      *(lc->elem + n) = *(la.elem + j);
      j--;
    } else if(*(la.elem + j) < *(lb.elem + k)){
      *(lc->elem + n) = *(la.elem + k);
      k--;
    } else {
      *(lc->elem + n) = *(la.elem + j);
      j--;
      k--;
    }
    n++;
    lc->length++;
  } 

  for ( ;j >= 0; j--){
    *(lc->elem + n) = *(la.elem + j);
    lc->length++;
  }

  for ( ;k >= 0; k--){
    *(lc->elem + n) = *(lb.elem + k);
    lc->length++;
  }
}
```

This one is from the book.

```
void MergeList(sqList la,sqList lb,sqList *lc){
  ElemType *pa,*pb,*pc,*pa_first,*pb_first;

  pa = la.elem + la.length - 1;
  pb = lb.elem + lb.length - 1;
  pc = lc->elem;

  pa_first = la.elem;
  pb_first = lb.elem;

  while(pa >= pa_first && pb >= pb_first){
    if(*pa > *pb)
      *pc++ = *pa--;
    else if(*pa < *pb)
      *pc++ = *pb--;
    else{
      *pc++ = *pa-- = *pb--;

    }
    lc->length++;

  }

  while(pa >= pa_first)
  *pc++ = *pa--;
  while(pb >= pb_first)
  *pc++ = *pb--;
}
```

Comment: This is missing a lot of context. We need a [Minimum, Complete Viable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to comment more. One thing to note is your variable names are infuriatingly opaque. Instead of `j`, which means nothing, name them something that implies what they do, or keep them scoped to the `for` loop so their utility is easily understood. What is `sqList`? How do we test this code?

Comment: First question: Output of your program is same as output of the one from the book?

Comment: You could simplify your syntax a bit by replacing all instances of eg `*(la.elem + k)` with `la.elem[k]`

Comment: The book is wrong, don't trust it. Their way of traversing an array backwards has undefined behaviour.  Your code is wrong (where n is changed in the last two loops?) Their code is also wrong (thwy don't change lc->length). Write `lc->elem[n]` instead of `*(lc->elem + n)` etc.

Comment: I'd say they're both bad due to lack of comments/documentation, poor choice of variable names (are you deliberately trying to make it hard to read to save some bytes of source code by using the shortest and least descriptive variable names possible?), and inconsistent and awful brace style.

Comment: Apart from the code and the book, also change the teacher. Judging your code is their job, doing so with the label "junk" is unhelpful. Not giving any explanation is only acceptable if you did not participate in any way in the lessons lectures, have not demonstrated effort to keep up with the class and even have annoyed them seriously recently on top of that. Only in that case, I could feel with the teacher and see a point in forcing you to actually work for knowledge. And of course that does not describe the way you act and how seriously you take the class, does it?

Comment: The code in the book is very sloppy: `*pc++ = *pa-- = *pb--;` modifies the `la` list for no reason. It relies on non portable assumptions such as `pa < pa_first` when `pa` is decremented while already equal to `pa_first`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a big difference between these two algorithms?

They are not doing the same so **yes, there is a big difference**

Your code has a bug which I guess is a classic copy-and-paste error. This line is wrong:

```
} else if(*(la.elem + j) < *(lb.elem + k)){
  *(lc->elem + n) = *(la.elem + k);    // ERROR... la.elem should be lb.elem
  k--;
} else {
```

Besides that the calculation of `lc->length` differs. In this code from the book:

```
while(pa >= pa_first)
    *pc++ = *pa--;
```

there is no increment but in your code

```
  for ( ;j >= 0; j--){
    *(lc->elem + n) = *(la.elem + j);
    lc->length++;
  }
```

there is. So again there is a difference. I guess the book is wrong and you are right.

The code in the book decrements a pointer and compare it to a pointer to the first element. Since the pointer being decremented will end up pointing before the first element the code has undefined behavior.

> My teacher told me that my code was junk,Why?

A teacher shouldn't say that.... and the teacher should at least explain why.

When evaluating code there can be several things to focus on:

- Functionality, i.e. is it doing what is should - this is **top priority**
- Performance, i.e. does the code execute with the speed you need
- Maintainability, i.e. is the code easy to read and understand and maintain.

Your code is not easy to read but as the code in the book is wrong I'll still prefer your code (after fixing the typo bug).

One simple example that you could change to increase readability:

```
*(la.elem + j) --> la.elem[j]
```

Also notice that the book has code that ain't easy to read. Look at this line from the book:

```
*pc++ = *pa-- = *pb--;
```

As reader of the code one can only think: "what is this code supposed to do?"

Comment: `*pc++ = *pa-- = *pb--;` is most probably incorrect: why modify `*pa`? So is the loop logic, comparing `pa` to `pa_first` as it eventually points before the array. Not to mention hiding pointers behind typedefs... Hence the code in the book **is** *junk*.

Comment: @chqrlie Fully agree. The code makes no sense.... except it does increment/decrement all three pointers in a one-liner. Not very readable/maintainable. It would be likely that some developer would change the code to just `*pc++ = *pa--;` and thereby break the functionality. All in all, it seems to fair to call the code in the book junk.

Answer (score 1):

My refactoring...

Changes made:

- made `MergeList` return the list, so the caller can do things like `resultList = MergeList(...` to make it a lot more obvious what was effected.
- changed variable names so they're more descriptive
- added "space before left brace" everywhere
- added "space after comma" everywhere
- added "space around operators" everywhere
- replaced pointer calculations with array lookups (see Jeremy Friesner's comment)
- replaced excessively complex `for()` shenanigans (use of comma, empty pieces) with simpler/easier to read loops
- added documentation (before start of function)
- added comments in function
- added `const` to source lists

Code:

```
// Construct a new list sorted by descending order of "elem" by merging data from
// two existing lists that are already sorted by descending order of "elem".
//
// WARNINGS:
//   If both source lists are not sorted the resulting list will not be sorted.
//   Caller MUST ensure that enough memory is allocate for the resulting list before calling this function.

sqList *MergeList(const sqList list_a, const sqList list_b, sqList *result_list) {
  int j, k, n = 0;

  // Do entries from both source lists until there's nothing left in at least one of the source lists

  j = list_a.length - 1;
  k = list_b.length - 1;
  while(j >= 0 && k >= 0) {
    if (list_a.elem[j] > list_b.elem[k]) {
      result_list->elem[n] = list_a.elem[j];
      j--;
    } else if(list_a.elem[j] < list_b.elem[k]) {
      result_list->elem[n] = list_a.elem[k];
      k--;
    } else {
      result_list->elem[n] = list_a.elem[j];
      j--;
      k--;
    }
    n++;
    result_list->length++;
  } 

  // If all entries in list_a haven't been consumed, copy the remaining entries to the result list

  while(j >= 0) {
    result_list->elem[n] = list_a.elem[j];
    result_list->length++;
    j--;
  }

  // If all entries in list_b haven't been consumped, copy the remaining entries to the result list

  while (k >= 0) {
    result_list->elem[n] = list_b.elem[k];
    result_list->length++;
    k--;
  }

  return result_list;
}
```

Comment: I doubt that a (probably very good) code solution, along with detailed explanation, really helps OP on the long-term. They have other more serious problems, either with the book, with the teacher or something even more threateningly serious.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I don't really care about OP's problem. My motives are purely selfish (I'm trying to reduce the amount of time I spend trying to decipher other people's code in future). Fortunately, OP can benefit from my selfishness. (even if it doesn't solve their more serious problem). ;-)

Comment: Hmm, so you do not intend this Q/A pair to be of any use for anybody? The question as is surely does not really help future readers and you do not care about OPs problem. So what purpose does your answer support? Note that OP asks for explanations why the code might be considered bad, not for a perfect code. So I doubt that they will benefit from your selfishness and they most likely will not be able to benefit from an explanation-free list of applied changes.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I think you've overlooked the `:-)` (indicating that I'm joking) at the end of my previous comment. However, if you want to a serious philosophical discussion about the motivations of everyone that helps others; I would be tempted to put forward the "selfishness is the real root of all altruism" theory (e.g. trying to please a god by helping others for your own gain in an after-life, trying to make yourself feel better about yourself, trying to "win" by getting a high score in a system that uses gamification techniques to peddle adverts, ...).

Comment: `result_list->elem[n] = list_a.elem[k];` --> `result_list->elem[n] = list_b.elem[k];`

Comment: Have you tried the code? I don't think it's doing what your description says.

Comment: @4386427: I only changed the code to make it more readable (while deliberately trying to not change its behavior). Maybe my description is correct (and the original code was buggy), and maybe my description is wrong (and the original code was correct). The only important thing is that the OP learns to document their code (so that other people can determine if the code does or doesn't do what it should do).

Comment: well, it's your answer... if you don't mind that the description is wrong then just let it be.

Comment: `j` and `k` should get the array lengths and the comparison should use `<`. This would be more idiomatic and avoid the need for a signed type.

Comment: I don't think I'm making myself clear here. A piece of code like this might take 20 minutes to write initially, but while writing it and just after writing it the code will be read by the author about 10 times. Then for the next several years the code will be read another 50 times (by other team members for various reasons). Because code is read far more than its written, it's important to make sure it's readable/maintainable. A silly bug caused by a typo that would be found in less than 2 minutes the first time it's tested is irrelevant in comparison.

Comment: You should either initialize `result_list->length` to `0` or better just set it to `n` at the end of the function.

Comment: @Brendan very good remarks. Also code is far more difficult to read and verify than to write.

Comment: I did see the smiley, did not like it and just managed not to comment that I do not find anything funny about your attitude and the fact that you state it explicitly and then "soften" it with a smiley - instead of spending the same time for improving the answer. Though admittedly, I do not see how to improve it by editing. And before you ask, I already explained why.